# Error while deleting last two rows data with condition from database in Android it deletes only 1 row

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here is my query to delete last two rows from database table

```
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND module_text ='" + module_type + "' AND id in (select id from my_chat order by id desc limit 2)";
```

When I go to next activity then again back on this activity (where I am using this query ) then query do not delete last two rows it delete last value only 1 row.

Comment: Seems a perfect candidate for a `"Why isn't my code working?"` closing vote. But I'll give you the time to add some code and the logcat, if any.

Comment: instead of running this query directly in code, use any SQL GUI tool like Webyog, pgadmin, phpmyadmin and run only this quert `DELETE
FROM my_chat
WHERE project_id ='" + project_id + "'
  AND module_text ='" + module_type + "'`. Find out how many rows is this query returning.

Comment: Please, Please, learn about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my query to delete last two rows with condition from database table.

```
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE module_text ='" + module_text + "' AND project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND id in (select id from my_chat where module_text ='" + module_text + "' order by id desc limit 2)";
```

Now this query delete last 2 rows of particular type.As I have a 3 different type in one table.